# Connecting to MongoDb using mongoose - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following config:

```
  "mongoose": {
    "url": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat",
    "options": {
      "server": {
        "socketOptions": {
          "keepAlive": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And connect to my DB

```
mongoose.connect(config.get('mogoose:url'), config.get('mongoose:options'))
```

But I'm getting such error:

```
node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:236
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)
```

I have already checked answers for [simular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303482/nodejs-connection-error-with-mongodb).

I'm quite new in Mongo, but following code works fine using native driver:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/chat', function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
//blabla
}
```

So answers for that question are not actual in my case.

Comment: that is it ``config``?

Comment: @AlexeyB. yes, it is

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem in your code is that you typo here `config.get('mogoose:url')`. You missed a `n` in `mongoose`. Thats why you trying connect to `undefined:27017`

Comment: Thank you so much! Feel myself foolish(