# MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, windows-firewall, econnrefused

I just added MongoDB to the dependencies of my Node.js project created with the `npm init` command. My index.js code is:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
assert.equal(null, err);
console.log("Connected successfully to server");

db.close();
});
```

But when I execute the code it throws the following error:

```
AssertionError: null == { MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

I really don't know how to fix it. I followed some guides that reported the same error but I couldn't fix it.

Should I poen a port on my modem? Should I replace "localhost" with my IP? Should I do anything else?

Please help me!

**UPDATE:**

I installed a MongoDB server on my Android device and replacing the `url` variable with `mongodb://ANDROID-DEVICE-LOCAL-IP:27017/mydatabase` it now works.

How can I accomplish it placing the database on my computer? Is the firewall blocking incoming connections? Is this why it works on Android but not on Windows?

Comment: Are you sure that your mongo instance is running on localhost (with port 27017)?

Comment: did you find this thread which looks similar to your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386464/econnrefused-error-when-connecting-to-mongodb-from-node-js

Comment: @Areca No, I'm not sure.

Comment: @minhtuannguyen I tried following the Anshul's instructions, but typing "lsof" in the Windows cmd it returns "lsof is not a command".

Comment: @Salvatore Rago lsof  is just a unix command.

Comment: for windows os you need to run mongod in one terminal and in another terminal run your server code

Comment: @minhtuannguyen So how can I fix it?

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe When I run mongod in my terminal it immediately stops executing and prints "shutting down with code: 100"

Comment: Make sure your Internet speed. If your net is slow it will be like that only...I too face this problem several times.Don't affraid it will connect.Keep on trying...And see my answer.It helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue!

I ran `mongod -dbpath "MY-PATH"` in the cmd and now it works.

The error occurred because nothing was listening on 27017 port. Now the `mongod` program is listening for connections on that port and so the connection from my project is no more refused.

Answer (score 0):

Make a configuration file like `config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    'secretKey': '12345-67890-09876-54321',
    'mongoUrl' : 'mongodb://localhost:27017/cubs'
}
```

And require that file in your server code

```
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});
```

Comment: This code prints out "Cannot find module mongoose". Should I install the mongoose pakage?

Comment: Yess you have to install it by npm install mongoose

Comment: Thank you @Syed Ayesha Bebe but it didn't work for me. Luckily, as you can see in my answer, I fixed the issue