# MongoDB stopped working suddenly after days of development

Tags: node.js, mongodb

After a few days of developing using Nodejs and MongoDB today I'm getting this error when I want to get into the first page of my app:

> MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

[image]

And when I try to connect to db using mongodb compass:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ECONNREFUSED error when connecting to mongodb from node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386464/econnrefused-error-when-connecting-to-mongodb-from-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified if mongo is running in the background?
Run mongod in the terminal and see the response, maybe your mongo process is'nt running and then you cant connect to your local mongodb.

Comment: Please how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it.
Go to `Services -> search for "MongoDB Server"`.
Right Click on it and then Click on **Start**.

[image]