# Mongo Connection keeps closing

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, backend

This A console log

GET http://localhost:5000/api/goals/
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 508773a0-7900-49bb-932d-1a7ada6c3101
Host: localhost:5000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: [Maybe releated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20386464/7482427)

Comment: Apple also started using port:5000 on Monterey, so I had to remap all my local servers to 5001. IDK if that triggers `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED` or a different error.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me, I just had to run `npm start` on my command line to run the project before creating the GET request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).